# CUDA-compatible GLM (generalized linear model) routine

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, regression, glm

I've searched for a little bit now, but can't find a glm C function that runs on CUDA? Does anyone know if this is available somewhere? 
I need to run hundreds of simultaneous glm regressions on the same data set and using CUDA could help me.

Answer (score 1):

From within R, the [`gputools` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/gputools.pdf) has support for performing GLM regressions on GPUs.  The code is freely available, and you may either look for whether there is C code that can be used or whether you can make calls from your C program to R.

Further information on the package may be found at:

- http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/
- http://brainarray.mbni.med.umich.edu/Brainarray/Rgpgpu/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. To my knowledge, gputools uses an uncommented C library to perform the GLM regression, and I have not found the source code of it. I'll search more.

Comment: Can you simply make use of calls to R?  If so, then it can take care of the regressions for you.  You can call R from within C or as a standalone process or server.  Also, if you choose to use a CPU method, be sure to use all of the best math libraries you can, such as ATLAS or the Intel & AMD options.  In R, there's also a very fast regularized GLM solver called `glmnet`.

Comment: I am trying to run different regressions in parallel (on GPU), which I don't think is possible in R (please correct me if I'm wrong). R optimises the single regression using gputools. About calling R from within C, I don't think that running multiple R processes in parallel is a possibility. Again, please let me know if I'm wrong. Using a kernel looked like the natural solution to the problem to me, but I can't find any GLM function that runs on GPU, and this looked weird to me. Thanks for pointing me to glmnet.

Comment: @user943987 You can run as many instances of R as you want, they operate independently.

Comment: See the package in R base `parallel`.